# Unable to add a line chart with 3 series into a Google sheet using API

Tags: google-sheets, charts, arduino-esp32, gsheets

I have a project to monitorize some parameters with ESP32 (Arduino IDE sketch) and I save result into a gsheets. Every new day generate new sheet to save dates. After new sheet creation, I want to insert into sheet a line chart with 3 series using requests `addChart`. With one series is ok, but is more explicit evolution of 3 parameters so when I define 3 series in JSON I receive next error.

```json
"error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid requests[0].addChart: If specifying more than one sourceRange within a domain or series, each sourceRange across the domain & series must be in order and contiguous.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

Succinctly what I tried:

domain sources: A1:A1000 (time of event) on axis x
series1 sources: B1:B1000 (values of parameter A)
series2 sources: C1:C1000 (values of parameter B)
series2 sources: D1:D1000 (values of parameter C)

Using https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts this is result:

```json
{
  "requests": [
{
    "addChart": {
        "chart": {
            "spec": {
                "basicChart": {
                    "chartType": "LINE",
                    "domains": {
                        "domain": {
                            "sourceRange": {
                                "sources": [
                                    {
                                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                                        "endRowIndex": 1000,
                                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                        "endColumnIndex": 1,
                                        "sheetId": 1439439696
                                    },
                  {
                                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                                        "endRowIndex": 1000,
                                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                        "endColumnIndex": 1,
                                        "sheetId": 1439439696
                                    },
                  {
                                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                                        "endRowIndex": 1000,
                                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                        "endColumnIndex": 1,
                                        "sheetId": 1439439696
                                    }
                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "series": {
                        "series": {
                            "sourceRange": {
                                "sources": [
                  {
                                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                                        "endRowIndex": 1000,
                                        "startColumnIndex": 5,
                                        "endColumnIndex": 6,
                                        "sheetId": 1439439696
                                    },
                  {
                                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                                        "endRowIndex": 1000,
                                        "startColumnIndex": 6,
                                        "endColumnIndex": 7,
                                        "sheetId": 1439439696
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                                        "endRowIndex": 1000,
                                        "startColumnIndex": 7,
                                        "endColumnIndex": 8,
                                        "sheetId": 1439439696
                                    }
                  ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "position": {
                "overlayPosition": {
                    "anchorCell": {
                        "sheetId": 1439439696,
                        "rowIndex": 2,
                        "columnIndex": 2
                    }
       }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Where am I wrong?

[What I expected:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4m8Q.jpg)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The documentation has one entry for `domains`; your data has three entries. I'd delete the 2nd and third entry.  FWIW, I expect your data to fail on the `series` data - the documentation contains three `series`, but your data combines the data ranges under a single series heading. May I respectfully suggest that you need to revisit the sample contained in the documentation, and the method that you used to convert this to your scenario.

Comment: Hi! Thanks all. @ Tanaike I posted an image with my desire. @ Tedinoz. Maybe I mis undestand role of sourceRange for domains vs series. You can explain me how can I define each for my desire?

Comment: `You can explain me how can I define each for my desire?` No, I cannot; I don't know much more than you but I did read the documentation that you said that you had used and it is clear that you have made mistakes adapting it to your scenario. I suggest that you look at the sample request and your request side-by-side.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified request body as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

From your following condition,

> domain sources: A1:A1000 (time of event) on axis x
> series1 sources: B1:B1000 (values of parameter A)
> series2 sources: C1:C1000 (values of parameter B)
> series2 sources: D1:D1000 (values of parameter C)

In your showing condition, it seems that the columns "A" to "D" are used. But, when I saw your showing request body, it seems that the columns "F" to "H" are used. And also, unfortunately, it seems that your request body is an invalid structure for using the batchRequest. When these points are reflected in a sample request body, it become as follows.

#### Modified request body:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "addChart": {
        "chart": {
          "spec": {
            "basicChart": {
              "chartType": "LINE",
              "domains": [
                {
                  "domain": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 1439439696,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 1000,
                          "startColumnIndex": 0,
                          "endColumnIndex": 1
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "series": [
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 1439439696,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 1000,
                          "startColumnIndex": 1,
                          "endColumnIndex": 2
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 1439439696,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 1000,
                          "startColumnIndex": 2,
                          "endColumnIndex": 3
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 1439439696,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 1000,
                          "startColumnIndex": 3,
                          "endColumnIndex": 4
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "headerCount": 1
            }
          },
          "position": {
            "overlayPosition": {
              "anchorCell": {
                "sheetId": 1439439696,
                "rowIndex": 2,
                "columnIndex": 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- In this request body, columns "A" to "D" are used.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I do not know your actual Spreadsheet. But, when I tested this request body using a sample Spreadsheet and the sample values, no error occurred, and a new chart was inserted. If an error occurs, please confirm your sheet ID and values again.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddChartRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addchartrequest)

Comment: @Arthur Serban About `Thanks for the suggestion, it works`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer